# QGIS unable to open those old US Military map in GeoPDF format

Tags: qgis, geopdf

Files are from: https://maps.lib.utexas.edu/maps/topo/vietnam/

My PDF reader can read the image but when importing it into QGIS it gives me a cyan rectangle inside a black one which I suspect is the `NEATLINE` bounding box.

I tried using gdal_translate to convert them in GeoTIFF

```
gdal_translate ban_buc-5951-4.pdf test.tif -of GTiff
```

resulting in no error being thrown but `test.tif` is of the right dimension but all white

weirdly

```
gdalinfo -mdd LAYERS ban_buc-5951-4.pdf
```

don't show any layer names

I saw a `GDAL_USER_PWD`, would that mean that those file could be password protected?

Comment: I downloaded the map bac_kan-6153-2.pdf and in QGIS 3.16.11 it is displayed perfectly fine! I simply drag and dropped the file from my file browser to QGIS.

Comment: Works for me too. Converting to GTiff works too on the command line. Qgis 3.20.x - tested with a_luoi-6441-4.pdf (first on the list) and the  `ban_buc` one as in your question...

Comment: Opening in QGIS 3.20.0 on Win10 does not work for me, I just get a black frame, inside it's white. Viewing in a pdf viewer of the same file is fine, however.

Comment: works in QGIS 3.18 but not working in 3.20 same result as @Babel

Comment: Seems to be a bug - you should report

Comment: I'm on win10 and I tried on qgis 3.16 and 3.21 I read somewhere that a user that could open a geopdf qgis Linux but not windows. Did you try on windows too @Mapperz?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro (20H2)

Answer (score 1):

turns out it's a Windows related bug, after I installed gdal on wsl

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
```

converting the pdf into jpg, size went from `9.2MB` to `3.8MB` with no loss of quality

```
gdal_translate ban_buc-5951-4.pdf test.jpg -of JPEG
```

Then the jpg opens in QGIS on windows no problem. The only little annoyance is the image appear Cyan tinted as band 1 appears unset and display a min & max value of `1.79769e+308`. After setting the band 1 to red manually, all looks good.

I tried setting the band 1 to red during `gdal_translate`:

```
gdal_translate -of JPEG -ot Byte -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 \
   -colorinterp_1 red -colorinterp_2 green -colorinterp_3 blue \
   ban_buc-5951-4.pdf ban_buc-5951-4_wsl.jpg
```

But no luck, but oh well good enough for me